# jQuery: get element from server onclick work

Tags: jquery

jQuery: get  element from server onclick work

```
$(function() {
   $('.class1 a, .class2 a').click(function(e) {    
      href = $(this).attr("href");              
      $.post(href,function(data) { 
         $('#content').html('');        
         $('#content').append(data);          
      });   
   });
});
```

if class2 back form server such as ..,that onclick function doesn't work on this class,how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `preventDefault`:

```
$('.class1 a, .class2 a').click(function(e) {    
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); this not the problem

Comment: @miket Your ajax request can't work without `preventDefault`, because as I can see your link is not empty and it's not a hash

Comment: The full code contains  e.preventDefault();,above is a fragment

Comment: If you click a tag within class1,then in container there's a a tag within class2 back from sever ,but this class2 a tag onclick doesnt work

Comment: @miket As **Stefan** write you need http://api.jquery.com/live/ or http://api.jquery.com/on/ on container of this elements, which one to use depends on your jquery version.

Comment: I Change to  $('.class1 a, .class2 a').on("click", function(e),and thange to v1.83 ,it seems not work just the same,lemme try live...

Comment: @miket `on` usage must look like: $(document).on("click", '.class1 a, .class2 a', function(e){ ... }) where `document` better to change on static container.

Comment: Thanks! $(document).on("click", '.class1 a, .class2 a', function(e){ ... }) also works!

Answer (score 1):

Try using '`on`' with a filter on 'class1 a, class2 a' on the body elemnt instead of searching the page for all classes.

Explanation: `$('.class1 a, .class2 a').` searches for all elements an adds a event. When you add content later on, the event isn't added to it.

Comment: if class1 a and  class2 are not back from sever ,even up to class8 it's works ok.

Comment: The problme is how to get the element from server onclick work

Comment: Stefan is right ,by the clue Stefan give I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815856/jquery-click-function-vs-inline-onclick